# YouTube Player API Iframe in phonegap off lights when runing

Tags: cordova, phonegap, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I use the youtube player on my phonegap project, but I have a problem when the player is running in the app if I launch the full screen, then after a while the device lights are off, and if I shrink it works normally. I tried to solve the problem but could not, could anyone help me?